# How can I install Websphere MQ Client on a Debian server?

Tags: debian, ibm-mq

This is one of those brain-dead things that I need to do for most the new development servers I set up at work. We used to have the steps documented on our wiki, but that got wiped out recently and so I had to figure this out again.

Without the MQ client packages installed, I was seeing the following error when trying to install a Python MQ client library:

```
In file included from mqclient.c:2:0:

module.h:6:18: fatal error: cmqc.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For future reference, here are the steps that worked for me. These assume you are logged in as `root` on the **Debian server**. These are for **version 7.0.1.10**, but I imagine can be more or less easily adapted to other versions.

#### 1. Install `alien` for `rpm` packages

If not yet installed on your server:

```
apt-get install alien
```

#### 2. Download IBM Websphere package

I believe the 7.0.1 versions can be found [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24019253), along with links to other versions.

#### 3. Unzip package in `/tmp/mqclient` directory and accept license

```
mkdir /tmp/mqclient
cp mqc7_7.0.1.10_linuxx86.tar.gz /tmp/mqclient
tar zxvf mqc7_7.0.1.10_linuxx86.tar.gz
./mqlicense.sh
```

Select the appropriate option to accept the license.

#### 4. Set up mqm user

```
adduser mqm
usermod -m -d /var/mqm mqm
```

#### 5. Install MQSeries packages

```
alien --scripts --to-deb MQSeriesRuntime-7.0.1-10.i386.rpm
alien --scripts --to-deb MQSeriesClient-7.0.1-10.i386.rpm
alien --scripts --to-deb MQSeriesSDK-7.0.1-10.i386.rpm
dpkg -i mqseriesruntime_7.0.1-10_i386.deb
dpkg -i mqseriesclient_7.0.1-10_i386.deb
dpkg -i mqseriessdk_7.0.1-10_i386.deb
```

And, voila, hopefully that does it. Remember to double check the paths in these steps against the ones you are actually using for your particular package and best of luck.